# What is the difference between uploading a file on CDN and having a file cached by CDN?

Tags: performance, cdn, bandwidth

I have a website which is cached by CDN cloudfare. I have some js/css files which I want to upload.

What is the difference in terms of performance and bandwidth consumed by my website between uploading the files onto my own website which is cached by Cloudfare versus directly uploading the files onto Cloudfare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference will be minimal, because ultimately it's all served from Cloudflare.

Cloudflare will occasionally fetch the original file if you're hosting it yourself, but this will happen rarely and not make any tangible difference to either bandwidth or speed.

Hosting it yourself has the added benefit that you can easily change providers if you need to. It is also probably easier to set up logistically, since your whole site with all its static assets lives in the one place.